# Calling a MC REST API from within a Code Resource Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs

Is it possible to call the Increment Column https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/putIncrementColumnValueByKey.html REST API from within a code resource page using SSJS?

It requires the PUT method.

Has anyone done this / maybe have a working example?

Alternatively, is there another way that the column (or entire row, i.e. all columns) can be updated using SSJS (or AMPScript if need be I suppose).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, via Script.Util.HttpRequest function. You can see a blog post I made **[here](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/)** for details.

Below is a sample of using this script for a PUT call in SSJS:

```js
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var accessToken = {{yourToken}};
var url = 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/{{ContentID}}'

var payload = '{{yourPayload}}';

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.method = "PUT"; /*** You can change the method here ***/
  req.postData = payload;

  var resp = req.send();
</script>
```

Now there are some other considerations around this that you need to take into account when using it, so I would highly recommend reading the article or otherwise doing further research on this function prior to trying to implement and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Gortonington's answer, in terms of alternatives for incrementing a number row in a DE from within a code resource,

- there is AMPScript Add()function - https://ampscript.guide/add/ which you can combine with lookup() and upsert(), those two can be SSJS or ampscript.
- instead of AMPscript, you can leverage plain javascript math
  (supported as to: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_serverSideJavaScript.html?q=math, "All functions native to JavaScript, such as arrays, math functions, the EVAL function, and try catch blocks work with server-side JavaScript." )